# Swift 3: CNLabeledValue as Parameter

Tags: swift3

Just upgrade to Swift 3. After open and convert my codes I found lots of errors. One of them is about `CNLabeledValue`.

With Swift 2.3, it works well with:

```
func myFunc(contactItems: [CNLabeledValue]) -> String {
    ....
}
```

With Swift 3, it gives me the error message:

> Reference to generic type 'CNLabeledValue' requires arguments in
>   <...>.

After I fixed it with XCode, it changed to:

```
func myFunc(contactItems: [CNLabeledValue<AnyObject>]) -> String {
    ....
}
```

However, XCode gives me error message with this fix:

> Type 'AnyObject' does not conform to protocol 'NSCopying'.

I know the error is because of the generic type but I don't know how to declare with `CNLabeledValue`. My purpose is to store all the `CNLabeledValue` including phone number, email, address etc to one array.

Any help will be appreciate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use generics

```
func myFunc<T: NSCopying>(contactItems: [CNLabeledValue<T>]) -> String {
  ...
}
```